# What does .asInstanceOf[Foo[_ <: Bar]] mean?

Tags: scala, iterator

I am new to Scala and came across this line of code while going through a sample scala project. Can someone please explain to me the purpose of bold code below:

```
struct.iterator().asInstanceOf[Iterator[_ <: Product2[Any, Any]]])
```

I understand that we are generating an iterator for the struct object, but what exactly is the purpose of the asInstanceOf function here and what difference does it make as somewhere else in the same program, the iterator was generated simply by:

```
struct.iterator()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct.iterator().asInstanceOf[Iterator[_ <: Product2[Any, Any]]])
```

lets get it part by part.

`.asInstanceOf` - it's similar to javas cast operator it changes type to:

`Iterator[type]` - data structures that allow to iterate over a sequence of elements

`_ <: Product2[Any, Any]` - here it get's a bit tricky. A <: B means that B must be subtype of A

for details please visit:
http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/variances.html and http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/01/covariance-and-contravariance-in-scala/

If you want to know more about Covariance and Contravariance please check Martin's Odersky video on coursera.

Comment: Here the  _ refers to Any type ?

Comment: Not really "Any", more like the iterator type param. I'm not shure a out that